# How use PyQt without GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want create python server application using `PyQt4` without GUI ( signal/slots, threads, process and other core patterns ).
  How i can create this?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392471/python-pyqt-is-it-possible-to-use-qthread-with-a-non-gui-program ??

Comment: I did't find this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the Qt EventLoop without a GUI you can use `QCoreApplication` instead of `QApplication`: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html

From the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html#details):

> The QCoreApplication class provides an event loop for console Qt
>   applications.
>
> This class is used by non-GUI applications to provide their event
>   loop. For non-GUI application that uses Qt, there should be exactly
>   one QCoreApplication object. For GUI applications, see QApplication.
>
> QCoreApplication contains the main event loop, where all events from
>   the operating system (e.g., timer and network events) and other
>   sources are processed and dispatched. It also handles the
>   application's initialization and finalization, as well as system-wide
>   and application-wide settings.